# How to create and access a memory block with Key in c++ without STL

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory

I have created a memory block like following

```
typedef struct tPersistNav{
UInt8 DriverID;
const char  *Start[NUM_START_LOC][STRING_SIZE];
const char  *End[NUM_START_LOC][STRING_SIZE];
UInt8 Matrix[NUM_START_LOC][NUM_DEST_LOC][DAYS_OF_WEEK] [HOURS_OF_DAY];

}tpersisnav;

tpersisnav *memory=new tpersisnav
```

My problem is I want to create multiple blocks of this memory based on DriverID and need to access the same block with DriverID key only. for eg, if driver ID =1 then it should access the block of above memory that maps to driver id=1 only.

Any pointers will be helpful

Comment: Questions: (i) Why not use the STL (i.e. containers provided by the standard library)? (ii) Are the driver ids consecutive integers, i.e. 1,...,n?

Comment: I have restrictions on using STL because for embedded real time application, its slow and Driver ID may not be consecutive integers

Comment: I recommend that you try using STL (either a `std::vector` if it the ids are consecutive, or a `std::unordered_map` if they are not), and find it out if it's too slow. Testing this is much easier than coding your own mapping, esp. if your ambition is to create something faster than what comes with the standard library.

Comment: Also, your question seems already to have been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866878/c-hash-table-w-o-using-stl

Comment: BTW, `UInt8` seems allow only 256 possibilities, so `std::map` or `std::lower_bound` on sorted array would do the job in less than 8 key comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. We cannot use any STLs unfortunately. Do you suggest creating Hash table of above Data type to be only solution?

Comment: Why tagging **stl** if you don't want it ?

Answer (score 0):

A hash table seems like a lot of overhead if your key is an unsigned byte. You could just use an array of 256 pointers. That reduces the code to a minimum and the space overhead of the NULL pointers is probably not a killer. It's a constant static space overhead, so there's no need for dynamic allocation, if that's something you're trying to avoid.

If you were expecting there to be actually be a lot fewer than 256 keys, you could use a double-indirect scheme: Use a vector of 256 bytes which contain the index into a small vector of block pointers. That way, two or more keyIds can share a single block; that's unlikely to be useful except in the case of unassigned keys, all of which would have the index of a NULL pointer in the block pointer list. Still not much code; the space overhead is potentially up to 25% more (if you use all 256 key ids), but potentially half as much (if you use less than 64 key ids). That assumes you either are prepared to reallocate the block pointer list, or you know its maximum size in advance.

All of the above assume that the keys are randomly distributed over the range [0, 255]. If they are, instead, consecutively assigned starting from 0, the problem is obviously much simpler.

Comment: Thanks rici for clarification. If you can share a  small code snippet, it will be very helpful